# How to save text pattern into different list python

Tags: python, list

Example :

I need to save the text between START_PATTERN and END_PATTERN in different list.

START_PATTERN

abc

xyz

END_PATTERN

START_PATTERN

efg

pqr

END_PATTERN

I see the below error: 
    outT[i].append(line)
IndexError: list index out of range

```
i = 0
with open(fpath) as file:
    match = False
    newfile = None

    for line in file:
        if re.match(START_PATTERN, line):
            match = True
            newfile = open('my_new_file', 'w')
            i=i+1
            outT[i] =[]
            continue
        elif re.match(END_PATTERN, line):
            match = False
            newfile.close()
            continue
        elif match:
            #list1.insert(i,i)
            #outT.insert(i,line)
            outT[i].append(line)
            newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. LMK when you do and I'll undo my downvote. See [ask] for advice.

Comment: I need to store abc xyz in one list. and efg pqr in another list.   Currently I see error at outT[i].append(line)

Comment: Not to be rude, but that's a statement, not a question.

Comment: My question is : How do I create two different list so that I can store the text between the pattern in two different list . I am unable to create two different list within the for loop.

Comment: Gotcha. Please [edit] the question to say that. You should also provide a [mre] including  the definitions of all your variables and the full error message.

Comment: Sure . My bad. I will edit the question and add error message.

Comment: You have too many things happening here, all of them wrong. Break it down into smaller tasks, and get each one to work before you do the next part.

Comment: You have not included *all* your variables, such as `outT`, or do you suppose `outT` is not relevant to your particular error message? You're one vote away from your question being closed.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the code now.

Comment: If  `outT` is not initialized before you execute the assignment `outT[i] =[]`, this too will fail. What if you initially have `outT = []` and then `outT.append([])`, so it is a list of lists? The last list in `outT` would be `outT[-1]` and so `outT[-1].append(line)` would append `line` to the most recently added list.

Comment: I tried initializing outT outside for loop , still I see the same error "     outT[i]
IndexError: list index out of range"   How do I initialize outT

Comment: I edited my previous comment. Take a look. In other words, try not to use index `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I mean:

```
outT = [] # we will have a list of lists
with open(fpath) as file:
    match = False
    newfile = None

    for line in file:
        if re.match(START_PATTERN, line):
            match = True
            newfile = open('my_new_file', 'w')
            outT.append([]) # add a new empty list
            continue
        elif re.match(END_PATTERN, line):
            match = False
            newfile.close()
            continue
        elif match:
            outT[-1].append(line) # append line to the last added list
            newfile.write(line)
```

I can't vouch for the rest of your logic; you may end up with lots of empty lists.

Comment: Yes this is working perfect. Thank you very much :)